# Elastic Beanstalk with Default Docker Container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to get a default docker container on elastic beanstalk. As in one of the ones where you can just say "docker run cassandra" and it downloads it and runs it. I know you can do this with ECS, but I need it on elastic beanstalk. I've been trying to figure this out for so long. I have even tried CodeBuild because then I can do it from the buildspec file, but I haven't been able to download docker with it.

Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Comment: So I kind of fixed this problem. I am now using a python project (just their default - I don't care as it's not actually doing anything) and added a folder named ".ebextensions" to my project folder, and in it a file named "config.config" (although I think you can call it whatever you want as long as the extension is .config) then in that I installed docker and and ran "docker run Cassandra".